# Prove set Inclusivity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I need help proving the following

> Suppose $A,B \subseteq X$.
>
> Prove that if $X \setminus B \subseteq X \setminus A$, then $A \subseteq B$.

I really need to see an example of how to do these types of problems in general. My attempt is below, but I would prefer to see a worked proof if possible.

"$ \implies $": Suppose that there exists some $t \in B\subseteq X \implies t \in X$. Now $X \setminus B \subseteq X \setminus A$ so $t \notin  A$. Therefore $A \subseteq B$.

"$ \impliedby $": Suppose that there exists some $t \in A\subseteq B\implies t \in B$. Now, if $A \subset B$ then $X \setminus B$ contains no values of $A$. Therefore $X \setminus B \subseteq X \setminus A$.

Comment: You can read the expression "every element not in B is also not in A", which means that if some $t$ is in $A$, it must be in $B$ since otherwise it would violate the statement.

Comment: Also what you tried to prove with arrows going both ways would be stronger than the original statement and not necessary. Also the attempt in the first direction I think is lacking and does not prove. For the part $t$ very well could be in $A$. Sorry if I miss something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume $X-B\subseteq X - A $.

Choose any $a \in A$. Then we claim that $a \in B$ as well. Suppose on the contrary this is not true. i.e. $a \notin B$.

Then $a \in X$ and $a \notin B$ implies $a \in X - B$.

Then since $X-B\subseteq X - A $ we also have $a \in X - A$.

This is equivalent to saying $x \in X$ and $x \notin A$.

In particular, this contradicts our assumption that $a \in A$. Hence $a \in B$ necessarily.

Then $A \subseteq B$ as required.

Comment: That is much shorter than my attempt. Would my attempt still be "correct" though?

Comment: For your forward direction you let $t \in B$. Then t should not be in X - B. I feel that there is a 'jump'in logic when you wrote $t \notin A$. As for your reverse direction I think it is ok. Though it would be better for you to closely stick to the definition of subset for starters. i.e. if $x \in B$ implies $x \in A$ then B is a subset of A etc...

Answer (score 1):

To show $A \subseteq B$, we need to show that for any $x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B$.

We proceed using the contrapositive approach i.e. we instead prove $x \not \in B \Rightarrow x \not \in A$

Suppose $x \not \in B$

By definition, $X\setminus B=\{x \in X, x \not\in B\}$

So, $x \in X\setminus B$

Since $X\setminus B \subseteq X\setminus A$, we have $x \in X\setminus A$.

By definition, $X\setminus A=\{x \in X, x \not\in A\}$

So, $x \not \in A$.